# Notification bubbles from nothing in C#

Tags: c#

in a C# application that has no graphics at all, and does a bunch of network operations, I need to be able to show notification bubbles (on top of everything, for a few seconds) near the icon tray on certain events.

I've been looking at this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx

But with no success. The problem with it is that the windows designed there won't show on asynchroneous events. It seems that I need a main form first on which I add delegates for it to work, which I have no need for.

All options I've seen so far require me to have a form in my application, but that won't happen. Is it impossible then to have these bubbles ? Any ideas ? There must be a way to add an icon in the tray popping messages inconditionally and without GUI right ?

Comment: Is your app WinForms (without forms) or a console app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from [Systray icon for Console application](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=84738) and [Creating balloon tooltip in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276005/creating-balloon-tooltip-in-c-sharp)

Add a reference to both System.Windows.Forms and System.Drawing.

**Update**:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
...

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = new NotifyIcon(this.components);
    item.Visible = true;
    item.Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information;
    item.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Balloon title", "Balloon text", ToolTipIcon.Info);
}
```

Also it can be that popups are [disabled in registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729).

Comment: This example also does not work for me. The trick is to set the tray icon: `icon.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;`.

Comment: I've updated the example and verified on my side  - thank you for pointing into correct solution

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class, it allows you to put icons into the notification area as well as doing balloon notifications which is what you're after.

Comment: Note you need to add a reference to assembly `System.Windows.Forms` and use the namespace `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: `NotifyIcon` class requires `System.Windows.Forms` to be imported, maybe OP does not want it...

Comment: @Marco Thats kind of like asking to do XML serialisation without referencing `System.Xml`...