# Creating Notification Form like Antivirus

Tags: c#

I have an programme that in his load test to show up an Notification

```
if (DateTime.Today.ToString() == AlreadyDate)
{
    formNotification.show();
}
```

its succed to show but i want it to show like an antivirus notification
Thanks <3

Comment: Antivirus like "warning your system is infected click download now" ... none of us are that dumb.

Comment: Check the [link][1] it is already been answered


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240059/notification-bubbles-from-nothing-in-c-sharp

Comment: What you mean by Dumb ?
i mean that the dialog will appear in the corner what ever
the resolution is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this WPF library can help you http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon