# make my form active / show on first position of all other running applications

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a simple winform application which I scheduled on my machine to execute daily at a regular intervals. The issue here is the form is not displaying on top / screen when all other applications are running, when I press the Window + D buttons I could see my form running below of all other applications and also its not showing in the "task bar" either.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Note: The application written in C#.NET.

Comment: If it's something what popups on screen in the middel of work, then consider using [baloon tooltip like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6276005/1997232) popup in the tray. With the rest we need to see the code. See [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried setting `TopMost` to true for your form?

Comment: [Window not activated when the application is run from Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394232/7444103)

Comment: Thanks MarkusAnd. Setting the property "TopMost" flag to "True" resolved the issue.